# how to make mongo db start after ubuntu startup

Tags: mongodb, shell

mongo connection failed in terminal every time after ubuntu startup then after running the command `sudo service mongod start` it is working fine. I am using ubuntu 18.04. How to fix it that it may run always without the above command?

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

`sudo systemctl enable mongod`

Reboot your machine and check if the service is up.

`sudo systemctl status mongod`

Checking out the manpage will give you a lot of information.

See systemctl manpage

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/systemctl.1.html